# AVFoundation and other frameworks causing "exception" with Core Data app

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, avfoundation, uimanageddocument

**When I add various frameworks, pictured below (the ones marked in red), my app throws an exception at save. When the app is restarted all data is lost.**

I am creating a document based cored data app. All seems ok until I add some frameworks needed to finish the app. By "exception" I mean if I add an "all exceptions" breakpoint the app will stop if I try to save the core data managed document. If I ignore the exception all works until I restart the app, at which point the document is recreated and all saved data is lost. The frameworks that seem to be conflicting with my core data setup : AVFoundation, Twitter, and Social.

[image]

Note: (Extra info may be helpful) If I build the app and then add the add these frameworks then rebuild, all works fine as expected. Only when I delete the app from my device then rebuild with these frameworks already included I get the exception and issue described.

Strangely, autosave seems to work fine. It's only when I use: `[myManagedDocument saveToURL:myManagedDocument.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:handler];` that I get the exception.

Comment: Not all exceptions are fatal.  I know that AVFoundation sometimes throws non-fatal exceptions internally in its C++ code when it's playing stuff.  If you simply remove the All Exceptions breakpoint, is this when you get the problem of the document not appearing on re-launch?  Also, does the document save fine if you remove those frameworks?  Are you getting any errors in your logs?

Comment: @aethe I found out what was causing the problem. I was saving the project apparently before my load was done. I assume that a fetch is in progress. Still looking into it. Thanks for the comment.